Reload / refresh exoplayer if video freezes / stops (live streaming)
I have a very simple Android app designed to continuously stream a single live M3U8 URL. However, after running for a while (minutes or hours), the video occasionally freezes.
How can I detect when the video has stopped playing live and automatically refresh the player to resume streaming?
I tried checking for player.STATE_ENDED, but it had no effect.
Any suggestions or best practices to handle this issue would be greatly appreciated!
 @UnstableApi
    private fun initializePlayer() {
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build().apply {
            binding.playerView.player = this
            val mediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(STREAM_URL))
            setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            playWhenReady = true
            prepare()

            addListener(object : Player.Listener {
                override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                    if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                        restartStream()
                    }
                }
            })

        }
    }

    @UnstableApi
    private fun restartStream() {
        exoPlayer?.let {
            it.stop()
            it.clearMediaItems()
            val mediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(STREAM_URL))
            it.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            it.prepare()
            it.playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

